# How to add custom middleware inside a Route group in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have a Route group in laravel which has middleware of `auth`

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth', function()
{
    //Routes
});
```

Now these routes are only available to logged in users. I have a situation that logged in users have privileges. I have some routes that are only to be visited by logged in users AND if they have privilege of `OWNER`

In function I have started a session and stored privilege value.

I did something like this

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth', function()
{
    //Routes
    if(session::get('privilege')
    {
        //Routes
    }
});
```

This isn't working neither it's appropriate method. Can anyone tell me how add middleware inside a middleware?

Comment: You can create your own middleware for that and use it as well with auth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a custom middleware called `OWNER`

```
php artisan make:middleware Owner
```

Will create a middleware file for you.
Then in the `public function` called `handle` u can do something like

```
if (Auth::user()->privilege == "OWNER") {
       return $next($request);
    }

return redirect('home');
```

So at the end your custom middleware will look something like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Owner
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
     if (Auth::user()->privilege == "OWNER") {
       return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect('home');

}
```

}

[More about Laravel Middelware here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware)

Comment: And use it like `Route::get()->middleware('Owner');` right?

Answer (score 3):

There should be no logic inside your routes file(s) - these should simply define routes and nothing else. What you should do is define middleware which verifies privileges/roles your user has, you can specify parameters which are passed to the middleware like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth', function() {

   Route::get('/my-route', 'Controller@method')->middleware('role:some_role');

   Route::get('/my-other-route', 'Controller@otherMethod')->middleware('role:some_other_role');

});
```

Then in your middleware, you can access that parameter via a third argument in the `handle` method. With that value, you could verify the privileged/role the user has and then decide if the user should access that route:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)
{
    // Do something with $role

    return $next($request);
}
```

If you're unsure about defining your own custom middleware, check out the docs here: https://laravel.com/docs/middleware